# What is speed of light with respect to light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, inertial-frames

If I was traveling at the speed of light and at the same time another person (adjacent to me) was too traveling with same speed, Will the relative velocity of that person with respect to me will be zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't travel at the speed of light, so the premise of your question is invalid.

That's not a flip response - it's actually the correct answer. No proper time passes on a null geodesic (i.e. something moving at the speed of light), so there can't be any kind of conscious thought or measurement process. It's meaningless to ask what something moving at the speed of light "sees," because you need time to elapse in order to experience anything.

Comment: Means at speed of light, time stops, everything stays right at its place except of that single photon. So will that photon see another photon moving or another photon will also stops as time stopped?

Comment: @AmanMaurya Photons can't see.

Comment: @AmanMaurya More seriously, if you do insist on talking about the photon's perspective, it's probably better to think of it as seeing everything else moving infinitely fast and compressed into an instant, not frozen in place forever. So it doesn't have time to see anything.

Comment: If I say, I switch off and on the torch twice giving off two light pulses, now those two are moving at the same speed with respect to me. But for a photon, the other photon is moving at speed of light. Now we shouldn't say that relativity should apply to 'conscious' observer who can perceive time as we do. So a photon is not observing the speed but it's an event and the events are defined in special relativity. So those two photons never collide each other with respect to me, nor with respect to themselves. Why is that ?

Comment: @Prabhat Why would you expect the photons to collide from anyone's perspective?

Comment: A photon is an inertial frame, so one photon will consider other photon as moving at speed of light and itself at rest, so likely the photon in its perspective will expect the photon to come towards it and eventually pass through it.

Comment: @Prabhat A photon does not have a frame, so it doesn't make sense to say whether it's inertial or not. A Lorentz coordinate frame for a timelike observer can be thought of as orthogonal coordinate basis of one timelike vector and three spacelike vectors, such that the timelike vector is instantaneously aligned with the particle's four-velocity. But a photon doesn't have a timelike four-velocity, so you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The situation cannot happen. It is impossible for an observer to travel at the speed of light.

The only thing that can travel at the speed of light is light (and any other massless particle, but only gluons are also massless, but they have other properties that would prevent you from seeing them).

For an observer travelling at nearly the speed of light, any other object travelling at that same speed in the same direction will have a relative speed of 0. As you increase your speed, the situation stays the same.

To any subluminal observer, light travels at the speed of light. But if we looked at the limits of the equations of special relativity, an object approaching the speed of light would experience increasing time dilation and length contraction. At arbitrarily high speeds, the time they experience becomes arbitrarily small and the length they observe also becomes arbitrarily small. So to any observer traveling at the speed of light, their entire travel is instantaneous and covers no distance. Nothing else exists in their universe except the point where they start traveling and the point they stop traveling.